# Get an object from ObservableColelction with condition

Tags: object, observablecollection, conditional-statements

I have an ObservableColection totalsCol and want to retrieve an object whose id matches the specified id. I coded as :

```
IEnumerable<Totals> ie = totalsCol.Where(a => a.IdCTS == ct1.TOR_Id);
 if (ie.Count() > 1)
 {
    // Update the TotalCts of Totals object
    ie.ElementAt(0).TotalCTS = ct1.TotalCts;
     CalculateTotalsPercent();
 }
```

I get ie.count as null. Whereas it has 3 records. And on debugging, I can see that under Source of base.

Where am I wrong here ? I beleive the way am updating the the value with ie.ElementAt will reflect changes in totalsCol observableCollection.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented :

```
totalsCol.First(a => a.IdCTS == ct1.TOR_Id);
```

and solved the issue.